# plot the spline for different values of z coordinate

Tags: matlab

i have the matrix of points in (x,y,z)  coordinate sequence as follows

```
a=[   4.946977  11.00563       -0.80

      5.081908  11.11679    -0.80


      5.212485  11.00879    -0.80

      5.28981   10.89013    -0.80

      5.581149  10.86267    -0.80

      5.774127  10.79532    -0.80
]
```

As `z-coordinate` is same(i.e, -0.800) other than zero. Now by using `spline` command in `matlab`, i want to fit a curve through these (x,y) points in a plane having `z-coordinate` -0.800 but matlab plots the curve in default plane of z coordinate having value zero.
I know it is easy, but i cant find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just need a spline in 2D, and then you can translate it to the plane `z = -0.8`.

```
x =

   4.9470
   5.0819
   5.2125
   5.2898
   5.5811
   5.7741
y =

   11.006
   11.117
   11.009
   10.890
   10.863
   10.795

clf
plot(x,y,'+');
hold on
pp = spline(x,y); % pp stands for piecewise polynomial
xx = linspace(4.94, 5.77, 100);
yy = ppval(pp, xx); % evaluate the xx in the piecewise polynomial
plot(xx,yy);
```

[image: spline in 2d]

```
figure
plot3(xx,yy,yy*0-0.8);
```

[image: spline embedded in 3d]